# HDMI seems to be dead

Tags: pi-3b+, hdmi

We have almost 300 RPi3B+ with monitors connected via HDMI.

These RPis are supplied with power via GPIO pins 2 and 4 (5V, 3A). Also from the same PSU monitors for these RPis also supplied with power (12V, 2A).

For some reason on 3 RPis we got HDMI fully inoperative, like a hardware issue. We tried all the recommendations from [this post](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#No_HDMI_output_at_all) and nothing was helpful.

To check if there are any problems with OS (Raspbian) we just used SDs from RPis with inoperative HDMI on another RPi. Everything works fine on this new RPi.

So what can damage HDMI? We suspect some grounding problems but are still not sure.

Comment: what is the area of failure? ... RPi, cable, display, power supply, etc

Comment: `on 3 RPis we got HDMI fully inoperative` - but other than that, those 3 Pi's work fine?

Comment: The area of failure is RPi itself... Yes, works fine, even with SDs from failed ones.